# adding icons to top pannel in 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04. I want to add application icons on top pannel but as you people mentioned the super+alt+right click is not working for me. 'add to panel' window is not getting opened. please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Unity it is not possible to add icons to the top panel. Only to the Unity side launcher.

At login you may choose the Gnome interface and there you will be able to add icons to the top panel.